# How to run without vectors with c++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to execute this code without using vectors?
Can this program be run without vectors in the polygon class?
If possible, how should I modify the code?
And is it right to write the copy constructor and the move constructor as it is now?

It's so hard to do C++ while playing Python. Help me.

Thank you.

**Polygon.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct C2D {
    double x, y;
};

class Polygon {
    int point;
    vector<C2D> arr;
public:
    Polygon(int point_, C2D arr_[]) : arr(point_) {
        point = point_;
        memcpy(arr.data(), arr_, sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };
    Polygon(Polygon& p) : arr(p.point) {
        point = p.point;
        memcpy(arr.data(), p.arr.data(), sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };
    Polygon(Polygon&& p) {
        point = p.point;
        memcpy(arr.data(), p.arr.data(), sizeof(C2D) * point);
        p.point = 0;
        delete[]p.arr.data();
    };
    void print() const {
        cout << "Polygon information" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
            cout << i + 1<< "point" << " : " << arr[i].x << ", " << arr[i].y << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    };

    double area_result() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < point; i++) {
            sum += ccw(arr[0].x, arr[i - 1].x, arr[i].x, arr[0].y, arr[i - 1].y, arr[i].y);
        }
        return fabs(sum);
    }

    static double ccw(double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3) {
        double res = x1 * y2 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1;
        res += (-y1 * x2 - y2 * x3 - y3 * x1);
        return res / 2;
    }

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main() {
    int point;
    C2D* c2d;

    cout << "point : ";
    cin >> point;
    cout << endl;

    c2d = new C2D[point];

    for (int i = 0; i < point; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << "x : ";
        cin >> c2d[i].x;
        cout << i + 1 << "y : ";
        cin >> c2d[i].y;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    Polygon p(point, c2d);
    p.print();

    cout << "Polygon area : " << p.area_result() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible? Yes. But why would you want to?

Comment: Your `Polygon` code makes very little sense: you shouldn't mix C++ `vector`s and manual memory management like `new[]`/`delete[]`. No need to manually implement any copy/move operations on `Polygon` as well, just follow [the rule of zero](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-zero.html). If "getting rid of `vector`" is not the home assignment, I'd recommend just using `vector`s everywhere.

Comment: Every single operation on `arr` is undefined here. You're `memcpy`ing data without resizing the vector first, and trying to `delete` its internal array.

Comment: You will simplify everything with `c2d` being a `vector`

Comment: I would do some reading/practice on learning how to use c-style arrays (as in, arrays in the C language). In doing so you'll learn how to use malloc/realloc/free.

Comment: @Elliott: That is *entirely* the wrong advice to give to a C++ novice.  Ideally, idiomatic C++ should not have C-style arrays, malloc / new, or free / destroy in it *at all*. [Stop teaching C.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk&list=FLe5cxHN7iNybQISW1NIY_QQ)

Comment: Is this a homework requirement to not use `std::vector`? In that case, I suggest you write `namespace homework { template <typename T> class vector; }`

Comment: @DevSolar, I think that understanding how a container works teaches a beginner how to correctly use it, and (more to the point) it directly answers what we all know the OP's is asking: If I know how to solve a question with `std::vector` but it's not allowed in the homework, how do I go around it? Well the simplest answer (and the one the teacher is likely trying to get the student to do) is to make the container.

Comment: `delete[]p.arr.data();` Ooof......

Comment: @DevSolar Using it in production, and knowing _how_ to do it, are two very different things.

Comment: @Elliott: If your instructor disallows `<vector>` and insists on you using C-style arrays, find an instructor that actually teaches C++ and doesn't waste your time. There is zero, I repeat, **zero** need to "know how C arrays work, first" in order to understand how containers work. Actually, quite a ot of the knowledge to be gained from learning C first is positively harmful when eventually transitioning to idiomatic C++.

Comment: @DevSolar, we're getting off topic here, but agree to disagree. I'm fine with teachers doing it the other way, but I think learning c-style first is fine too.

Comment: @Elliott: Disagreeing is fine, but please take the time to watch that video from CppCon that I linked in my first comment, perhaps it will change your opinion. My opinion is that teaching C style first is positively harmful.

Comment: I think you got a few answers. However, reconsider your question: What would you do with either yes or no as answer? What are your thoughts on these questions? Please read [ask] to get some insight into good questions. As a new user here, also take the [tour].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is using `vector` exactly like a C style array, so you can replace it with such an array with minimum changes.

In fact, it will make your code simpler to read, since you will not be misusing a C++ object like a C variable.

```
class Polygon {
    int point;
    C2D *arr;
public:

    Polygon(int point_, C2D arr_[]) {
        point = point_;
        arr = new C2D[point];
        //you should check here allocation is successful
        memcpy(arr, arr_, sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };

    Polygon(Polygon& p)  {
        point = p.point;
        arr = new C2D[point];
        memcpy(arr, p.arr, sizeof(C2D) * point);
    };

    Polygon(Polygon&& p) {
        point = p.point;
        arr = p.arr;
        p.point = 0;
        p.arr = null;
    };

    //you will need to add a destructor to clean up memory
    ~Polygon() {
        delete [] arr;
    }
};
```

That said, as the comments suggest, this is a bad practice.
If you have some constraints, such as a limited C++ environment lacking a `vector` implementation, a need to interface your code with another language / runtime, or homework requirement, you should add them to your question for suggestions on better solution.

Comment: `new` does not silently return null pointers. Also note that calling `memcpy` will skip any (copy) constructors defined for C2D. You should write the simple element-by-element copy and let the compiler optimize it into a `memcpy` if it can. The copy constructor should take a `const Polygon&`. Finally, you should follow the rule of 5 and also implement `operator=` to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: You should use `std::copy` actually.

Comment: @leoChoi: It is perhaps what you *wanted*, but not what you *needed*. Check the last paragraph of the answer. Unless you can *state a good reason* why `<vector>` is not an option for you (and that should be in the question itself), using C arrays and manual memory management instead is, if not outright wrong, then at the very least very, very poor design. You mentioned Python. C++ can be just as simple. You just have to stop using C...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings But you are forgetting [rule 386](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @bitmask Hehe indeed

Comment: @Botje C2D does not have any copy constructors and I was trying to retain as much of the OP code as possible. I admit I did not remember `new` throws exception, but I also intentionally left the error handling code to the OPs discretion, since we don't have enough information to know what should be done if allocation fails.

Answer (score -1):

**Don't.**

Vectors are one of those no-brainer improvements of C++ over C. Don't try to code around them, learn how to use them properly. You will see that many lines of code and many sources of headaches go away when you *actually code C++*.

**Polygon.hpp**

```
#ifndef POLYGON_HPP
#define POLYGON_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

struct C2D
{
    double x, y;
};

class Polygon 
{
    public:
        Polygon( unsigned points_, std::vector<C2D> const & arr_ ) : points( points_ ), arr( arr_ ) {}

        Polygon( Polygon & p ) : points( p.points ), arr( p.arr ) {}

        Polygon( Polygon && p ) : points( p.points )
        {
            arr.swap( p.arr );
        }

        friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, Polygon const & p );

        double area_result()
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for ( unsigned i = 1; i < points; ++i )
            {
                sum += ccw( arr[0].x, arr[i - 1].x, arr[i].x, arr[0].y, arr[i - 1].y, arr[i].y );
            }
            return std::fabs( sum );
        }

        static double ccw( double x1, double x2, double x3, double y1, double y2, double y3 )
        {
            double res = x1 * y2 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1;
            res += ( -y1 * x2 - y2 * x3 - y3 * x1 );
            return res / 2;
        }

    private:
        unsigned points;
        std::vector<C2D> arr;

};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Polygon.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, Polygon const & p )
{
    out << "Polygon information" << std::endl;

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < p.points; ++i )
    {
        out << ( i + 1 ) << "point : " << p.arr[i].x << ", " << p.arr[i].y << std::endl;
    }

    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    int points;
    std::vector<C2D> c2d;

    std::cout << "points : ";
    std::cin >> points;
    c2d.reserve( points );

    for (int i = 0; i < points; i++) {
        C2D coord;
        std::cout << i + 1 << "x : ";
        std::cin >> coord.x;
        std::cout << i + 1 << "y : ";
        std::cin >> coord.y;
        c2d.push_back( coord );
    }

    Polygon p( points, c2d );

    std::cout << p << "Polygon area : " << p.area_result() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @leoChoi: There is still lots of room for improvement in the code I posted, but I wanted to retain your original structure so that it is easier for you to spot what exactly I changed from your code, and see the reason behind it.

Comment: You didn't answer the question at all. You answered some other question.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: And that is where you are sorely mistaken. The only correct answer to "how do I do C++ with C arrays instead of `<vector>`" is "you don't" (unless you can actually *state* a reason why `<vector>` is not an option for you). And in that case, I'd still point to `<array>` before I'd go to `[]`, `new`, and `memcpy`. Feel free to disagree, or even downvote, but you won't get me to budge one bit on this.

Comment: Besides, the fact that the code in the Q already made use of `<vector>` is, for me, a very strong hint that the problem here is OP's lack of knowledge on how to use `<vector>` properly, not some kind of constraint of his environment.